# datetime2 causes stack error

Tags: datetime2

Anyone able to explain why this is? Here's a mwe. If I comment out the two `datetime2` lines, document compiles fine, otherwise failure occurs on `\opening`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
    margin=2cm,
    headlines=4,
    parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
    foldmarks=false,
    fromalign=right,
    fromrule=off,
    refline=dateleft,
    fromphone=false,
    fromemail=true,
    pagenumber=footright,
    fromlogo=false]{scrletter}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
        A. N. Other\\
        Someplace\\
        ZIP CODE%
    }
\opening{test}
\closing{cheers}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

log output

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\sym@date ->\if@orgdate \sym@date 
                                  \else \num@date \fi 
l.31         \opening{test}
                           
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your question ...  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch OK, done.

Comment: I think the two packages are not compatible. scrletter redefines \today at begin document. So even if you avoid the error you actually don't get the datetime2 commands.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two ways to avoid this error:

1. Add a global option `british`. (I noticed this because in the documentation of `datetime2` there are plenty of `\documentclass[british]{article}`.)
2. Load `babel` after `datetime2` (but this might not be a very good idea)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
    margin=2cm,
    headlines=4,
    parskip=full,
    british,
    ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
    foldmarks=false,
    fromalign=right,
    fromrule=off,
    refline=dateleft,
    fromphone=false,
    fromemail=true,
    pagenumber=footright,
    fromlogo=false]{scrletter}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% \usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
% \DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
        A. N. Other\\
        Someplace\\
        ZIP CODE%
    }
\opening{test}
\closing{cheers}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First way doesn't work. Only putting babel after datetime2 irrespective of whether global option 'british' is added, works. Why is loading babel after datetime2 not advisable?